# Laravel 4.2.8 > many to many > create a new related model and attach > error

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

don´t get it why this error occurs when inserting a new zip-code and relate it to an existing company using laravels eloquent belongsToMany feature.

here is my setup:

**Error**

```
file: "...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php"
line: 411
message: "postcode"
type: "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException"
```

**Insertcode**

```
$postcode = new Postcode(array('postcode' => $data['plz']));
Company::find($data['id'])->postcodes()->save($postcode);
```

**Company Model**

```
class Company extends Eloquent {

    public function postcodes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Postcode');
    }
}
```

**Postcode Model**

```
class Postcode extends Eloquent {

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Company');
    }

}
```

Table **postcodes**

```
| id | postcode |
```

Table **company_postcode**

```
| id | postcode_id | company_id |
```

Table **companies**

```
| id | name |
```

Does anybody know why this isn´t working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says

> MassAssignmentException

That is because you are trying to mass assign `postcode`

```
new Postcode(array('postcode' => $data['plz']));
```

So make sure you whitelist the postcode variable as being mass assignable

```
class Company extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('postcode');

    public function postcodes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Postcode');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this helped ... but I had to declare $fillable in the Postcode-Model not in the Company one ... still testing

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to make it the postcode model - I copied the wrong part of your code :)